# How to efficiently find the common part between two lists

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, cluster-computing

There are two lists, which respectively represent two results of the clustering algorithm, such as com1 = [[1,2,3,4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]], where com1 represents a clustering result, [1,2,3,4] represents nodes 1,2,3,4 belong to the same class. [5,6,7,8] indicates that nodes 5,6,7,8 belong to the same class, and 9 belongs to a separate class. com2 = [[1, 2, 4], [3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]. Now, I need to find out the common parts between com1 and com2, such as [1,2,4],[5,6,7,8],[9].

Is there an efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why `[1,2,4]` is common?

Comment: So there can be variable number of clusters for the same number of elements?

Comment: Can you provide some more input/output?

Comment: com1 and com2 are the classification results of two different algorithms, A node can belong to only one class

Comment: Another example is as follows: com1 = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], com1 is the output result of one of the two algorithms. com2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8]] is the classification result of the other algorithm. Now we need to get the common part res = [[1,2,3],[6,7,8]] of these two clustering results, since the common part res of these two algorithms has been obtained, the remaining nodes 4 and 5 are then processed separately to get the final result. So the key step in our algorithm is to get the common part of the two clusters.

Comment: What about a case such as [[1,2], [3,4]] vs. [[2,3]] ?

Comment: I think you forgot to include [3] in your example's output. If not, please explain why [3] should be excluded, as it looks to be in the same situation as [1, 2, 4]: both are a subset of [1,2,3,4].

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that a given value can only occur in one sublist in `com1` and in one sublist in `com2`, we can observe the following:

Two values will belong to the same sublist in the result when they belong to the same sublist in `com1` and also in the same sublist in `com2`.

So we could collect for each value the two *indices* of the sublists they belong to: one index that identifies the sublist in `com1`, and another that identifies the sublist in `com2`.

We can use those pairs as *keys* that uniquely identify a target sublist, and populate those sublists accordinly:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def combine(com1, com2):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for com in com1, com2:
        for i, lst in enumerate(com):
            for val in lst:
                d[val].append(i)
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for val, key in d.items():
        res[tuple(key)].append(val)
    return list(res.values())

# Example 1
com1 = [[1,2,3,4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]
com2 = [[1, 2, 4], [3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]
print(combine(com1, com2))  # [[1, 2, 4], [3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]

# Example 2
com1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
com2 = [[1, 9], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]
print(combine(com1, com2))  # [[1], [2, 3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

If we assume an amortised constant time complexity for dictionary get/set actions, then this brings the total time complexity to O() where  represents the number of values in the list that gets partitioned.

Comment: In the first example, [3] does not seem to be desired.

Comment: I think the asker will have no problem in removing all sublists of size 1 if they don't want them in the result. Since they include [9] and exclude [3], I think they either missed it or have some unexplained logic. I assumed the first.

Comment: Although the question post specifies *"two lists, which respectively represent two results of the clustering algorithm"*, I think it would still be good to explicitly specify in your answer that your code relies on the fact that each item appears in at most one sublist of com1 and at most one sublist of com2. For instance, `combine([[1,2,3], [2,4]], [[1,2,3],[3,4]])` returns `[[1], [2], [3], [4]]`.

Comment: Added that assumption at the top of my answer just now. Thanks, @Stef

Comment: In such circumstances, I prefer to ask for clarifications before posting any answer. (Though clarifications rarely come.)